# How to add Lombok plugin to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed **Lombok** Plugin in **Intellij**. But I didn't find any plugins in Eclipse to install. Mine is Oxygen **Eclipse**. 
Is there any way to make the Lombok application to make work in Eclipse too.

Comment: have you tried https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse ?

Comment: No, let me try. By the way mine is not a enterprise version of eclipse. Does it support that?

Comment: I guess it even works with a current version of the Eclipse Java IDE instead of the two release behind version you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By following the below steps I am done with eclipse setup.

1. Download jar from  https://projectlombok.org/
2. Copy the lombok.jar into the root Eclipse folder and run the below command
   `java -jar lombok-1.16.12.jar`
3. This will open a small UI, where the location of the Eclipse installation can be specified. Usually the Eclipse installation will be found automatically and lombok can be installed or updated. Just press the Install / Update button and restart the IDE.

Comment: If its a maven project and if we add the lombok jar as dependency in pom with scope provided  , do we still need to install it as a plugin  in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, It is required to add.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, i am not the fans of using this approach to patch the eclipse. Moreover, in future, if i update eclipse to newer version, i might need to repeat again. I wish eclipse has a native support for lombok.

Answer (score 26):

Did you try this?

Go to *Help menu > Install new software > Add https://projectlombok.org/p2 > Install the Lombok plugin* and restart Eclipse.

Also you maybe can see the methods using the "Outline" view <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>.

I am on Eclipse Version 2020-12 (4.18.0).

Comment: The simplest answer that worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I had problems to install in my linux Ubuntu and It was the best approach.

Comment: This is the best answer and works like a charm. I tried all other ways by adding arguments to eclipse.ini file etc, but it only screwed things more in my eclipse and never worked. Adding via Install new software works perfect without any hassle of manual intervention.

Comment: Don't works. Before finishing of installation the Eclipse displays error dialog with this message: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.projectlombok.agent,1.18.24.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFileXXX.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFileXXX.jar
...